# Arduino & twitter can I connect?

Tags: twitter, arduino

Anybody here can explain how to connect Arduino and Twitter? Or better how to automate Arduino from IFTTT? It was one of the reasons I started with Arduino.
Now I understand Twitter API is changed, I saw some proxies which allows connecting using HTTP, but I need solution for searching Twitter posts in order to automate via IFTTT

Answer (score 0):

I had a project earlier in the year where we used the Twitter API from a PC to get the data.  Then we manipulated the data and pumped the resultant data to the arduino via the serial port.

In this scenario the arduino is basically a display driver and the program on the PC does the heavy lifting.